# why is JSON.NET outputting DateTime values in my DataTable in this format?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a service that is serializing a DataTable into JSON and when I retrieve the service data I want to deserialize back to a DataTable... problem is, I can't because JSON.NET is adding something in the serialization that it then doesn't recognize...

All DateTime values in my DataTable end up looking like this:

```
"date_time_value":{"IsValidDateTime":true,"Year":2020,"Month":4,"Day":20,"Hour":14,"Minute":50,"Second":46,"Microsecond":0,"Millisecond":0}
```

JSON.NET outputs the serialized JSON like this... so I would expect it to know how to deserialize it as well... how do I get the date serialized as a simple string so that I can deserialize the data?

EDIT: I have a controller method returning the data.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Query")]
public ActionResult<string> Query([FromBody]SqlDto content)
{
    return Ok(_mySqlGenericService.Query(content.HostnameOrIpAddress, content.Username, content.Password, content.SqlCommand, content.SqlParameters));
}
```

And the method that the controller is calling:

```
public string Query(string hostnameOrIp, string username, string password, string sqlCommand, List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters = null)
{
    var mySqlDatabaseConnection = new MySqlDatabaseConnection(hostnameOrIp, username, password);

    DataTable dt = mySqlDatabaseConnection.Query(sqlCommand, ConvertQueryParamListToTupleList(sqlParameters));

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
}
```

The `MySqlDatabaseConnection` class simply connects to a MySQL database and the `Query` method returns a DataTable.

Note that whether I return the DataTable directly or use the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method to convert it to a JSON string before returning, the return value ends up being the same JSON.

EDIT2: For anyone who may come looking at this question later, I was wrongly assuming what a DataTable actually was at a low level... I assumed it was just some form of string array and that's completely wrong... the DataTable object is far more complex than I realized.  It handles inputs from different data sources in different ways (so MS SQL data looks different than MySQL data since they are loaded to a DataTable in different object formats).

Comment: Do you control the service?  If so, can you show us the code that is creating this JSON?

Comment: I just updated my question to show the relevant code, please let me know if you need more... I can post the MySqlDatabaseConnection.Query() method if you think that's relevant... though it shouldn't affect the outcome of anything since the DataTable returns fine from that method

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a `DataTable` rather than something more appropriate (e.g. a concrete type with properties that you define)?

Comment: The actual reasoning is a bit complicated but with this particular service I need to be able to handle any generic query and any generic results... That's why I am using a DataTable... Annoyingly, this works fine with generic output from Microsoft SQL but for some reason the serialization doesn't seem to work properly with MySQL data and I can't figure out why... They're both DataTable objects before serialization

Comment: Also, I understand the security issues and all that... It's heavily locked down.  But it needs to allow generic data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the database driver you're using doesn't use `System.DateTime` to represent dates and it probably shouldn't anyway. It appears to be a [`MySqlDateTime`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_Types_MySqlDateTime.htm) type judging by the properties it serialized as. Json.net doesn't recognize this type but you probably have a fallback converter that treats it as an object. I ran some tests myself on this type and it converts to `null`.

I don't know if you'll find a ready-made converter for this, it probably exists somewhere, fortunately it should be easy to create one.

```
public class MySqlDateTimeConverter : JsonConverter<MySqlDateTime>
{
    public override MySqlDateTime ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, MySqlDateTime existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dateTime = serializer.Deserialize(reader, typeof(DateTime));
        return new MySqlDateTime((DateTime)dateTime);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, MySqlDateTime value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dateTime = value.GetDateTime();
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I wrongly assumed MSSQL and MySQL data would be handled the same once they were both in the format of a DataTable... apparently I need to do more reading up on what a DataTable actually is, as I assumed it was just a big array of strings at a lower level, hence why I assumed all DataTables would behave the same... thanks for your explanation and code, plugging that in as a converter to the JsonConvert Serialize and Deserialize methods seems to have solved my problem